# Match strings between rows of a dataframe and report coordinates

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with hundreds of rows and looks something like this:

```
Gene = c("EIF4A1", "CAPNS1", "LDHA", "RPL38", "CCAR1")
Pep = c("TGKTATFAISILQQIELDLKA", "MFLVNSFLKGGGGG", "CAISILMKDLAD", "VITDKEKAEKLKQSL", "TPANYQLTQTAALQQQAA")
Seq = c("MSASQDSRSRDNGPDGMEPEGVIESNWNEIVDSFDDMNLSESLLRGIYAYGFEKPSAIQQRAILPCIKGYDVIAQAQSGTGKTATFAISILQQIELDLKATQALVL*",
          "MFLVNSFLKGGGGGGGGGGGLGGGLGNVLGGLISGAGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGTAMRILGGVISAISEAAAQYNPES*",
          "MATLKDQLIYNLLKEEQTPQNKITVVGVGAVGMACAISILMKDLADELALVDVIEDKLKGEMMDLQHGSLFLRTPKIVSGKDVFTE",
          "MPRKIEEIKDFLLTARRKDAKSVKIKKNKDNVKFKVRCSRYLYTLVITDKEKAEKLKQSLPPGLAVKELK*",
          "MAQFGGQKNPPWATQFTATAVSQPAALGVQQPSLLGASPTIYTQQTALAAAGLTTQTPANYQLTQTAALQQQAAAAAAALQQQYSQPQDQKSKENGASV")

df_in = data.frame(Gene, Pep, Seq)
```

I want to match sequences in `"Pep"` with sequences in `"Seq"` and report if the match is within the 1st, 2nd, 3rd or 4th quarter of the sequence in `"Seq"`. If the sequence falls in boundaries then consider quarter with >50% match.

Desired output data.frame:

```
df_out = data.frame(Gene, Pep, Seq, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I am new to R but heavily investing my time in analyzing my data with it. Was hoping somebody might have ideas (and possibly code) to solve this problem. Since, grep/stringr handles text so added those tags. But, honestly any tool (within R) would be just fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a first cut, you can use `regexpr` to find the index of the first match. Then use the index of the midpoint of the Pep to check which quarter it is in.

```
df_in = data.frame(Gene, Pep, Seq, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

mapply(function(pp, sq) {
        posn <- regexpr(pp, sq)[[1]]
        midpt <- (posn + posn + nchar(pp) - 1) / 2
        ceiling( midpt / nchar(sq) * 4 )
    }, df_in$Pep, df_in$Seq)
```

After this, you can start handling special cases like 1) if the exact string of Pep cannot be found in Seq, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much @chinsoon12. This worked perfectly. The output is not exactly the same as I wanted but even better :)